# Where can i find all files shared within a team in Microsoft Teams using the teams API?

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, office-addins, microsoft-graph-teams

I would like to get the files within a team, just like they have them in the files tab.
[image]

I would like to replicate this on my own tab, just can't find anything where to start from.

I would also like to download the contents of the file(get the content in some way, base64, uint array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know `team_id` and `channel_id`

To list all teams in an organization you need to get a list of groups that have  a `resourceProvisioningOptions` property that contains "**Team**".

Endpoint to list teams

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$select=id,resourceProvisioningOptions
```

Endpoint to list team's channels (use id from previous query)

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team_id}/channels
```

Endpoint to get files and folders

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/filesFolder
```

The query above returns metadata about [driveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Use `parentReference.driveId` and `id` in the next API call to get folders and files

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{id}/children
```

It returns a collection of `driveItems` with unique `id`.

- If `driveItem` represents a file then `file` property is not null.

For each item that represents the file you can call

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}
```

to get more details about the file.

- If `driveItem` represents a folder then `folder` property is not null.

For each item that represents the folder you can call

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}/children
```

to get more details about the folder or to get items inside the folder.

If you want to download the content then call

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}/content
```

Resources:

[List all teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0)

[Channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Get channel's files and folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-filesfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Download file content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: I would also like to download the contents of the file(get the content in some way, base64, uint array...

Comment: @Wet_Pantz I've updated my answer with an endpoint to download file content.

Comment: When i try this it says Acces token is empty. Where do i find the access token?

{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token is empty.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-03-29T13:03:58",
            "request-id": "20fbae85-6d93-4b51-9b3c-17d79dfaa441",
            "client-request-id": "20fbae85-6d93-4b51-9b3c-17d79dfaa441"
        }
    }
}

Comment: To get a token by using the client credentials grant, send a POST request to the /token Microsoft identity platform.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token